# What would be a nice architecture so I can pass information of eventual problems to a higher layer?

Tags: c#, architecture

I have a standard 3 layer project and my data layer either accesses the database or an API. I would like to be able to show information to the user in case there are problems occurring in the data layer.
I would like to show in the interface if there was any error (some required info by the API was not set, problems connecting to the database/API or any other problem that could happen).

Currently I would have an "out string error" parameter that would return the problem message. But this smells bad and this will also require my business layer to have the same paramter, which smells even worse.

What would be a nice architecture so I can pass information of eventual problems to a higher layer?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be two ways:

1. Raising some custom exception
2. Raising event at database layer and handle it in business layer.

Now while raising the event/exception at data layer you can pass the information which will help you in business layer.

The only change at business layer will be the listening of these events or catching these exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

I personally implement a log routine, where any error caught, gets logged application wide.

I show the errors, and informational logs, to the user inside the main app interface instead of throwing dialog box type errors. This might not be your specific scenario, but works well for me in my scenario, as I don't have to continually pass status / errors of data layer / business layer functions up the chain to the presentation layer.

The presentation layer periodically "looks for" any updates/errors/etc, retrieves them, and clears the "buffer".

Comment: Thanks! but in my case the error should be shown to the user and the application should be developed fast (it is a maintenance tool, not my project's main one), so creating this log/log checking mechanism would be too complex for my solution.